# Substitute text in a macro variable in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to change any instances of a period in a macro variable to underscore. What am I doing wrong?

```
%let pow=0.1;
%let x = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&pow,".","_"));
%put x=&x;
```

Output:

> x=0.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No quotes in a %sysfunc, unless you mean the quote character.  (Translate would have hidden the issue, at least, but TRANWRD was looking at &pow and trying to find "." and failing.)

```
%let pow=0.1;
%let x = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&pow,.,_));
%put x=&x;
```

Comment: This post saved my day, in particular the note about the quote character and the `%sysfunc`...